# Does anyone know how to change Firefox icons?

Tags: firefox, icons

I have found some nice firefox icons and I'd like to change my old icon for one new one.

I have logged in as a `root` and went to `usr/lib/firefox/icons` and pasted the new icon in, but after restart it doesnt appear. It just shows a red circle instead of the icon. How could I make firefox accept the new icon?

NOTE: I have just switched back to the root account and it works perfectly there, but when I wanna use it on my normal account it wont work. I have tried to copy the icon in the same way I copied it with the root account, but it wont let me do it. Is there a way to get root access on my normal account and copy the icon?

Comment: What icon are you talking about? A desktop icon?

Comment: @LnxSlck yes, the desktop icon of firefox.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `wont` to `won't`, `doesnt` to `doesn't`, and `wanna` to `want to` so that English translating software can render this page properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terminal, I had to use the command line `gksu nautilus` to be able to get permission for changing files. In this case, I needed the permission so that I could copy the new Firefox icon.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox may not have permission to access the new icon. Try giving it 777 or something. I don't know for sure though, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Make the icons readable by anyone, like this:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/firefox/icons/*
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesnt work. I type the command in the terminal and hit enter and nothing happens.

Comment: Nothing is suppose to happen, except the icon now appears on your user desktop

Comment: @LnxSlck This was my problem: gksu nautilus
I had permission issues and this command sorted it out.